# Use searchkick with an elasticsearch plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire, elasticsearch-plugin

How can I use [searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) with an elasticsearch plugin like this https://github.com/skroutz/elasticsearch-analysis-greeklish ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to change the default analyzers right now is to fork the gem.  Here's a good place to start:

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/master/lib/searchkick/reindex.rb#L97

Comment: Thank you Andrew for your great gems and your answer! I was thinking about that, a friend has done it as you suggest http://pastie.org/9111274 so it seems like it is currently the only way. Keep up :)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to modify `Searchkick::Reindex` module somewhere in lib/ext/ (if you are using rails) https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/master/lib/searchkick/reindex.rb and to post process searchkick_index_options call with custom code, which adds new analyzers into settings.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that there is a standalone [greeklish gem](https://github.com/skroutz/greeklish) that you might be able to use.